# Error using NSolve function please help

Tags: equation-solving

I have tried to use nsolve to solve this transcendental equation for the bound state of a finite well..

For some reason mathematica is just returning my exact input back to me

any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my input and output:

```
m = 9.11*10^-31;

b = 0.35*10^-9;

\[HBar] = 1.055*10^-34;

V = 1.602*10^-19;
```

and

```
NSolve[Sqrt[(2*m*x*b^2)/\[HBar]^2]*
   Tan[Sqrt[(2*m*x*b^2)/\[HBar]^2]] == Sqrt[(
  2*m*(V - x)*b^2)/\[HBar]^2], x]
```

$$
\text{NSolve}\left[\sqrt{\frac{2 b^2 m x}{\hbar ^2}} \tan \left(\sqrt{\frac{2 b^2 m x}{\hbar ^2}}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2 b^2 m (V-x)}{\hbar ^2}},x\right]
$$

with output of

```
NSolve[4.47806*10^9 Sqrt[x] Tan[4.47806*10^9 Sqrt[x]] == 
  4.47806*10^9 Sqrt[1.602*10^-19 - x], x]
```

$$
\text{NSolve}\left[4.47806\times 10^9 \sqrt{x} \tan \left(4.47806\times 10^9 \sqrt{x}\right)=4.47806\times 10^9 \sqrt{\text{1.602$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-19}-x},x\right]
$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: In addition to that, please, do not add images - add code instead.

Comment: by images do you mean the latex version of my code as posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[Sqrt[(2*m x b^2)/h^2]*Tan[Sqrt[(2*m x b^2)/h^2]] == Sqrt[(2*m*(V - x)*b^2)/h^2], {x, 5*10^-20}]

(*Output*)
{x -> 4.86164*10^-20}
```